# What 'sw' means in the fstab swap entry for 'mount options' column

Tags: fstab, swap

In my /etc/fstab file I have an entry for my swap as follows:

```
/root/swap swap swap sw 0 0
```

I have other machines and also I've seen online that sometimes they put default or xfs or other options. Then, I'm a little confused on what 'sw' means and what's for, and also which one would be the best option to put there and why.

Comment: What Unix are you using here? This seems to vary somewhat between the BSDs and Linux.

Comment: I'm using Centos 7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [the `fstab` manual on my system](http://man.openbsd.org/fstab):

> The fourth field, `fs_mntops`, describes the mount options associated with the filesystem. It is formatted as a comma separated list of options. It contains at least the type of mount (see `fs_type` below) plus any additional options appropriate to the filesystem type. [...]
>
> If `fs_type` is “rw”, “rq”, or “ro”
>        then the filesystem whose name is given in the `fs_file` field is normally
>        mounted read-write or read-only on the specified special file.  **If
>        `fs_type` is “sw” then the special file is made available as a piece of
>        swap space by the `swapon(8)` command at the end of the system reboot
>        procedure.**

So basically, `sw` is used to tell `swapon` (or `swapctl` on my system) that this is a valid candidate for use as swap space that will be added as part of the system start-up routine.

From [the manual describing `swapctl -A`](http://man.openbsd.org/swapon.8):

> This option causes `swapctl` to read the `/etc/fstab` file for devices and files with an “sw” type, and adds all these entries as swap devices. If no swap devices are configured, `swapctl` will exit with an error code.

That's on OpenBSD. On the *Ubuntu Linux* system that I have access to, neither manual mentions `sw` as a mount option for swap for some reason.

Comment: From the available documention on Linux one of two things are possible (a) the `sw` option doesn't do anything, and is simply a placeholder (b) tells `swapon` to activate the swap space. But why this should be necessary, I don't know, since the space is already specified as swap by the filesystem type. In any case, in view of the apparently wide usage of `sw` on Linux, this probably represents a lacuna in the documentation, and should probably be reported.

Comment: @FaheemMitha The `sw` may be changed to `xx` to explicitly _disable_ a swap partition.  So it's not completely useless. Again, that's from the `fstab` manual on OpenBSD.

Comment: I was only talking about Linux. The BSDs might well do things differently. Or it's possible the Linux and the BSDs do the same thing, but the Linux documentation is lacking. I suppose one would have to look at the source code.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by `If  fs_type is “sw”`. The fourth column isn't fs_type, it's mount options.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, the fourth field is the mount options (`fs_mntops`). These options contains the `fs_type`, the type of mount. The type is read-write (`rw` and `rq` (quota)), read-only (`ro`), or swap (`sw`) (or `xx` for disabled).

Answer (score 15):

For Linux, at least, based on a look at the net, this appears to be an example of "cargo culting". The evidence I've see suggests that this option isn't actually necessary or meaningful, but you need to put something there, because the `fstab` file syntax expects it. You can easily find examples of people using `defaults` and even just `pri=1` or whatever, leaving out both `defaults` and `sw`.

And it doesn't make sense that `swapon` would need to look at the mount options to check that it is swap, because `swapon` can already see it's swap by looking at the filesystem type. There are certainly mount options for swap that modify behavior, as documented in `man swapon`, but `sw` isn't one of them. So the evidence is that it is a placeholder, and `foobar` would do just as well as a placeholder

I can't be completely sure of this without looking at the source code of course.

Related, a Debian bug report complaining about this exact issue:
[mount: swapon(8) lacks explanation for sw and defaults options](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=647899)